# what is the best practice to review endpoint utterance in Luis dispatch model?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

what is the best way to enhance a dispatch model in LUIS, as checking the dispatch app asked utterances "review endpoint utterances" and updating it does not affect the original apps I have from Luis or QnA, should i always update the other apps manually based on the received endpoint utterances or there is a better practice for improving a dispatch bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.  Updating Dispatch app directly on LUIS portal is not currently recommended as the utterances added directly will be overridden (removed) when Dispatch app is refreshed via the "dispatch refresh" CLI command.  To add utterances shown in "Review Endpoint Utterances" to Dispatch, add them to a file (one line per utterance, one file per dispatch intent).  Add the intent file to Dispatch as source, ie:
dispatch add -t file -f <> --intentName <>

If the utterances are never seen in the underlying LUIS app, add them directly to the app.

Answer (score 0):

The Review Endpoint Utterances page shows you utterance by users and your tests as well, which you can quickly assign to intents to improve the model. To make changes to the model visible, you need to first Train then Publish